Can I get the content on an HTML file stored in SharePoint Online using Power Automate?
I have some HTML files stored in SharePoint.
Is it possible to retrieve the content in the file e.g target the body element or better get the whole table element.
My goal here is to retrieve the content and save it back to SharePoint as a page.
Any resources or tips would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

You can use Power Automate flow like below to get the whole content of HTML file stored in SharePoint online document library:

Output:

Reference: Get the HTML file from SP Asset library in Power Automate.

Thanks. Any idea How i can create a new page in SharePoint and insert the html to it

You're welcome! Check these: 1 and 2.
